# Blank chart is displayed when large amount of data passed

Tags: javascript, asp.net, teechart

I am binding the data to a DataGrid object on code behind in my asp.net page and using java script to find the output table, use "fromTable" method to populate the series.

I am getting a chart for 2 points with 10 minutes interval for one month period but when I try to get one year data for the same 2 points with 10 minutes interval, I get a blank chart (attached here) with labeled for X-Axis and Legends .

Also there seems to some script running behind which making the page non-responsive/freezes, I end up killing the page after some time.

Any help would be greatly appreciated,

Thanks.

Comment: I see no attachments. Could you please arrange a simple example project we can run as-is to reproduce the situation here?

Comment: Sorry, this was my first post here, I had to remove the attachment because I did not have the minimum 10 reputation need for one.

Comment: You can post your files using your favourite file hosting service.